# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getAbsolutePath()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm little bit confused, I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getAbsolutePath() (View: C:\Users\rust\Desktop\projectName\resources\views\container\index.blade.php)`

And my `show` method in my `ContainerController.php` looks like this  :

```
public function show($args = '')
    {
        if($document = Document::where('key', $args)->first()) {
            return response()->download(storage_path('app'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $document->getAbsolutePath());
        }

        $items = explode('/', $args);
        $department = Auth::user()->department;

        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Root')) {
            $department = Department::where('slug', '=', $items[0])->first();
            $items = array_slice($items, 1);
        }

        if($department == null) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        if(file_exists(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $department->slug . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $items)))
            && !is_dir(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $department->slug . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $items)))) {

            return response()->file(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $department->slug . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $items)));
        }

        $current_parent = 0;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $container = Container::where('slug', '=', $item)
                ->where('parent_id', '=', $current_parent)
                ->where('department_id', '=', $department->id)
                ->first();
            if(!$container) abort(404);
            $current_parent = $container->id;
        }

        $contents = Container::where('parent_id', '=', $current_parent)
            ->where('department_id', "=", $department->id)
            ->get();
        if (!($container = Container::find($current_parent))) {
            $container = $department;
        }

        return view('container.index', compact('container', 'contents', 'args'));
    }
```

I don't know what I did wrong, but I'm a little bit lost right now

Comment: Can you show us your `container/index.blade.php`?

Comment: It says your error is in view, are you making any calls in the view?

Comment: Should go without saying, but please don't vandalise your question. It'll be rolled back otherwise.

Comment: @rust That's because your question has an answer and that answer has been positively received. To be able to delete the question after the fact would be unfair on the time Vikash has spent trying to help you on this question. You can find the conditions for being able to self-delete a question [on the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Answer (score 0):

In your code... `$document` is the laravel collection.. not file object. Try load the file and then call `getAbsolutePath()` with that.

```
// code snippts.

if($document = Document::where('key', $args)->first()) {
            return response()->download(storage_path('app'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $document->getAbsolutePath());
}
```

**Edited:**
And in your `view` you are also using the collection with 
`$container->getAbsolutePath()` at line no: 65.

Comment: I have pointed you the wrong code in your view file.. check the `Edited` section.

Comment: You can comment that line and check if it works...

Comment: Would you like to link a docuement url in view correct?

Comment: comment in view, replace `{{ route('new-doc', ['args' => $container->getAbsolutePath()]) }}` with `#` just for the debug.

Comment: It says `Undefined variable: contents (View: C:\Users\rust\Desktop\projectName\resources\views\container\index.blade.php)`

Comment: Now comment first `if condition` in controller > action. Because you have used `=` assignment operator there... and it's returning from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195354/discussion-between-vikash-pathak-and-rust).